# same object giving different value, depending on another object is commented out or not

Tags: python, class, oop

I am a total beginner at OOP in Python. I am creating a simple class as a book and creating 2 instances as book_1 and book_2 of that. While I am printing values of them, printing page or name of book_1 is printing values from book_2, which is weird, when I am commenting out the book_2 part, then book_1 is returning the right value associated with book_1.

I have tried this code in 'Spyder' and 'Idle', both are giving the same result.
Please forgive my naiveness putting such a question, I am asking a question in this site for the first time. Thanks, everyone in advance for the help.

```
class book:
    def __init__(self,title,author,page):
        book.title = title
        book.author = author
        book.page = page

    bsize = 5
    bsize += 1

    def bookname(self):
        return(book.title + ' - by ' + book.author)


book_1 = book('pather daabi', 'bankim', 350)

# if I comment out the below line for book_2, book_1 is printing correctly

book_2 = book('sei samoi', 'sunil', 145)

print(book_1.page)
print(book_1.bookname())

# if I comment out the below line for book_2, book_1 is printing correctly

print(book.bookname(book_2))
print(book.bsize)
```

Comment: You're adding properties to the class, not the instances. `book.title` etc. Should be `self.title`

Comment: You need to use `self` which refers to the instance of `book`. Change your code to `self.title = title`, `self.author = author`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, totally understood, I believe this is a dumb mistake on my side. bsize is a class variable which I used to learn how it works. thanks, everyone, again!

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code:

```
class book:
    def __init__(self,title,author,page):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.page = page

    bsize = 5
    bsize += 1

    def bookname(self):
        return(self.title + ' - by ' + self.author)


book_1 = book('pather daabi', 'bankim', 350)

# if I comment out the below line for book_2, book_1 is printing correctly

book_2 = book('sei samoi', 'sunil', 145)

print(book_1.page)
print(book_1.bookname())

350
pather daabi - by bankim

# if I comment out the below line for book_2, book_1 is printing correctly

print(book.bookname(book_2))
print(book.bsize)


sei samoi - by sunil
6
```

You need to use `self` which refers to an instance of whatever class you're working with which is `book` in this case. I think this is normal practice or convention but try to have your class names be capitalized -- would be `Book` in this case. Nothing serious but just to follow convention. On another note: Not sure what `bsize` is for or what it's doing.